The Interplay between Fundamental Group and Differentiable Structure of Manifold
In algebraic topology, the fundamental group is a key invariant of a manifold. I'm interested in understanding how the smooth (differential) structure of a manifold influences its fundamental group and its covering spaces.
Specifically:

Are there examples of smooth manifolds where the differential structure imposes restrictions on the fundamental group that are not present in the purely topological category?
How does the smooth structure affect the classification or existence of certain types of covering spaces compared to the topological setting?

For instance, I’ve heard that exotic spheres can have different smooth structures but are topologically the same. Does this difference in smooth structure lead to different fundamental groups or covering space behaviors?
Any detailed examples or references to relevant theorems would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

$2$- and $3$-manifolds only have one differentiable structure, up to diffeomorphism,  but have different fundamental groups, see here.

Is there any reason to suppose there's a link? Also, what do you mean with "contradictory insights"? Sure you're not talking about contradictions in the mathematical sense of the word?

I interpret this question concretely as follows:
Question: If $M$ is a (connected) $n$-manifold, does knowing that $M$ is smoothable imply anything about the isomorphism type of $\pi_1(M)$?
The answer to this question is negative. This is handled by cases (in fact, these are partially even stronger statements)

In dimension $n\le 3$, every manifold has a smooth structure, unique up to diffeomorphism, so the assumption is redundant.
If $M$ is closed, $\pi_1(M)$ is finitely presented and, conversely, in dimension $n\ge4$, any finitely presented group is already the fundamental group of a closed smooth $n$-manifold by a surgery construction.
If $M$ is open in dimension $n=4$, then $M$ is smoothable, so the assumption is redundant.
It is always true that $\pi_1(M)$ is a countable group and, conversely, in dimension $n\ge5$, any countable group is already the fundamental group of an open $n$-manifold (in fact, of an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$).

This story does not really have a deep moral, in my opinion. The fundamental group is a very rough invariant and smooth manifolds a very flexible class of objects, so the negative answer to the question is rather circumstantial. The knowledge about manifolds required to make this observation is nonetheless deep.
To supply something hopefully in the spirit of what you are looking for, let me point out that such behavior does occur if you fix one of the two deficiencies I just mentioned:
If you take a stronger invariant like the entire homotopy type, the existence of smooth structures has lots of non-trivial implications. For example, the homotopy type of a simply connected, closed $4$-manifold is entirely determined by a homotopical invariant known as the intersection form and smoothness has a non-trivial implication about the signature of that intersection form; this is Rokhlin's theorem.
In the other direction, if instead of supplying a smooth structure, you instead supply the more rigid structure of a geometry, i.e. a Riemannian metric, the invariants known as curvature have a deep relationship with the fundamental group. It is a classic theorem of Myers that a complete Riemannian manifold whose Ricci curvature is bounded below by a positive multiple of the metric itself has $\pi_1(M)$ a finite group. It was conjectured by Milnor in 1968 that a complete Riemannian manifold with non-negative Ricci curvature has $\pi_1(M)$ a finitely generated group. There are many partial positive results, counter-examples in dimensions $\ge6$ were found only in $2023$ and the conjecture still remains open in the critical dimensions $4$ and $5$.
